# iphone/ipad - The dreaded Program received signal: “0”

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have an iphone app that always seems to crash after running it for a while (on the device only). Nothing in particular that I can see, it just seems to run out of memory or something. I get this:

```
Program received signal:  “0”.
```

When I last ran it with Allocations (Instruments), Live Bytes was only 12MB when it crashed, so it seems to have a lot of memory left over. What would be causing the above error message?

EDIT:
The app does a lot of things, including loading many images. The images are discarded when memory gets low, and like I said Live Bytes remains low to medium.

My question is more about the Program received signal: “0” error. What does it mean? It just seems to happen after running the app for a while.

Comment: What does your program do? Are you attempting to load a large image into a UIImageView?

Answer (score 0):

Without giving more information about what your program is doing, it's difficult to answer this question.

However, I have seen similar issues in the past when attempting to load a large image into a UIImageView (or several large images into multiple UIImageViews). Apple recommends resizing images larger than 1024 by 1024 before putting them into a UIImageView.

If this is not your problem, please edit your question to provide more details so I or others can give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've seen from personal experience, the only thing that causes it to do "Program received signal "0"" error is running out of memory.